# How to get distinct records from MySQL table with duplicate/varying Boolean value

Tags: mysql, if-statement, case, distinct

I have a table with following structure:

| Name | Subject | ExamType | Passed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bryan | Science | Theory | True |
| Bryan | Science | Practical | False |
| Joe | Science | Theory | True |
| Joe | Science | Practical | True |
| Jill | Science | Theory | False |
| Jill | Science | Practical | False |
| Jack | Science | Theory | False |
| Jack | Science | Practical | True |

We need to apply OR condition, so that if a student has passed in EITHER Theory OR Practical, he/she is considered Pass (i.e. True). So we need the following result:

| Name | Passed |
| --- | --- |
| Bryan | True |
| Joe | True |
| Jill | False |
| Jack | True |

How to apply condition across the rows to achieve the above result?

I tried using distinct and CASE but cant put my head around how to scan across multiple rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT
    Name,
    MAX(Passed) AS Passed
FROM
    YourTableName
GROUP BY
    Name;
```